# Tag synonym request: [django-auth] -> [django-authentication]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, retag-request

[django-auth](/questions/tagged/django-auth) (64 questions) and [django-authentication](/questions/tagged/django-authentication) (145 questions) are for the same topic.

I suggest that [django-auth](/questions/tagged/django-auth) be made a synonym of [django-authentication](/questions/tagged/django-authentication).

Comment: @Mat, thanks I've just made a correction!

Comment: Any opinions on the issue?